# Runtime Error in a recursive function : terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc' what(): std::bad_alloc

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, recursion, runtime-error

I  am using a recursive function `ans1` to find a suitable string ,
but I'm having runtime error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc**
```

```
void ans1(vector<int>a,int x , int val,string s,int req)
{
    if(x<0||val>req)
    return ;

    if(val==req)
    {
       cout<<s<<endl;
        return ;
    }
    char c='a'+x;
    
    ans1(a,x-1,val,s,req);
    s.push_back(c);
    ans1(a,x,val+a[x],s,req);

    
}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: How are you calling this function? Please make a [mre]. Also, if you just step through the program with a debugger, you should be able to find the issue yourself.

Comment: For what input value you are getting this error ?

Comment: You might try to use references for `a` and `s`, in order to reduce the amount of memory

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `a` by value!
This means that you are creating copy of `std::vector<int>` for each recursion step. If `a` is big the you allocating lots of memory. Change argument to `const vector<int>& a` and problem should be fixed.

In case of `s` problem is more complicated since you are modify it. You could use `string &s`, but you have to remember to restore old value when coming back from recursion, to avoid side effects.